# Iterate over nested maps

Tags: java, generics, nested-generics

I put together these methods to help iterate over nested maps (for [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15618457/823393)).

As you can clearly see, the first two methods are actually almost exactly the same apart from their generics and that one calls `iV` and the other calls `iiV`. Is there any way I could fold them into one method, or at least move the clear duplication of the mechanism into one place?

If done right it should be possible to iterate over nested maps of any depth.

```
// Iterating across Maps of Maps of Maps.
static <K1, K2, K3, V> Iterator<Iterator<Iterator<V>>> iiiV(Map<K1, Map<K2, Map<K3, V>>> mmm) {
  final Iterator<Map<K2, Map<K3, V>>> mmi = iV(mmm);
  return new Iterator<Iterator<Iterator<V>>>() {
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
      return mmi.hasNext();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Iterator<V>> next() {
      return iiV(mmi.next());
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
      mmi.remove();
    }
  };
}

// Iterating across Maps of Maps.
static <K1, K2, V> Iterator<Iterator<V>> iiV(Map<K1, Map<K2, V>> mm) {
  final Iterator<Map<K2, V>> mi = iV(mm);
  return new Iterator<Iterator<V>>() {
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
      return mi.hasNext();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<V> next() {
      return iV(mi.next());
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
      mi.remove();
    }
  };
}

// Iterating across Map values.
static <K, V> Iterator<V> iV(final Map<K, V> map) {
  return iV(map.entrySet().iterator());
}

// Iterating across Map.Entries.
static <K, V> Iterator<V> iV(final Iterator<Map.Entry<K, V>> mei) {
  return new Iterator<V>() {
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
      return mei.hasNext();
    }

    @Override
    public V next() {
      return mei.next().getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
      mei.remove();
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: If it is going to iterate on n-depth maps, what would be the method signature and the return type?

Comment: @khachik - Take a look at the full answer in the link. You can use `NestedIterator(NestedIterator(Iterator<Iterator<Iterator<V>>> i))` returning `Iterator<V>`. These methods are just helpers to build nested iterators out of nested `Map`s for the `NestedIterator` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
static <K, V> Iterator<V> iV(final Iterator<V> mei) {
   return new Iterator<V>() {
     @Override
     public boolean hasNext() {
       return mei.hasNext();
     }

     @Override
     public V next() {
       if (Iterator.class.isAssignableFrom(V.class)) {
         Iterator it = iV((Iterator)V);
         return it.hasNext() ? it.next() : ((Iterator)mei.next()).next();
       }
       else
         return mei.next().getValue();
     }

     @Override
     public void remove() {
       mei.remove();
    }
  };
}
```

(Not tested)

Comment: Not sure if you can do `V.class` due to type erasure but I like the idea. Perhaps `mei.getClass()` instead.

Comment: Oh, I think you're right. But `mei.getClass()` will just return `Iterator.class`. You should probably take one element and check this one with `element.getClass()`, but be careful considering empty Iterators etc. I have already had similar situations, and I think there is no cleaner solution... :(